# Book Class Footnotes Numbering

Tags: footnotes

In the book class, footnote numbering restarts with each new chapter. Is there a way I can have all footnotes numbered sequentially regardless of which chapter they appear in?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{The Book}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter One}

Here is some text.\footnote{And here is a footnote.}

\chapter{Chapter Two}

Here is some more text.\footnote{And here is another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

The second footnote should carry the number "2," not the number "1."

Comment: Indeed it is! I searched using the word "cumulative;" the question using the word "continuous" didn't appear.

Comment: The other answer does not work.